# Flutter - Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

No matter how hard I tried and looked for solutions online, none of them worked. It's strange because my old project is running fine, but when I tried to create a new project and run a basic counter app, it kept giving me an error. It's really frustrating when something that should be simple becomes so complicated.

```
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Retrying Gradle Build: #4, wait time: 800ms
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           1,925ms
```

I tried to change the  `classpath` -  *it works in the old project!*

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

also I tried

deleted the `gradle-wrapper.jar` file and run - *nothing works*

downgrade the `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
&
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all
```

I'm running the projects in VS-code

Answer (score 0):

Try using VPN.
Connect to the VPN then run your project, it may take a while as it the first time, I would also highly recommend that you run your project on a real phone, not on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why my project running after changing some Android files!

What I did!

`build.gradle`

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
```

to

```
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

`buil.gradle` in app folder

```
android {
    namespace "com.example.flutter_test"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```

to

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```

`gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

every `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

to

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutter_test">
```

Now I can run the projects without errors but I have quite curious to know why my projects running after changing these many things